# Возможно ли скрытие вопросов от конкретного участника?

Tags: поддержка, фильтрация-вопросов

Подскажите, пожалуйста, способы фильтрации списка вопросов по условию их авторства.
В "фильтрах" ленты я такой возможности не увидел, но возможно есть готовые сторонние решения? (например, расширение для браузера)

Или может существует способ добавления "личных меток", которые локальны для учетной записи, и не мешают другим? Такой вариант тоже помог бы, и он даже лучше.
Отфильтровать по обычным тематическим меткам - никак не получается, так как вопросы автора всегда используют именно те метки, которые отслеживаю.

Зачем это вообще потребовалось - для сохранения личной мотивации и "веры в проект", путём отрешения от случаев, когда модель SO вообще не работает применительно к отдельным участникам и их низкокачественным вопросам (то есть, чисто психологический момент).

Указать конкретно на вопрос/автора не могу по очевидным причинам, надеюсь на ваше понимание.

Comment: Встроенных средств точно нет. Нет даже возможности исключить отдельного юзера в поиске. Есть только поиск по постам конкретного участника через `user:id`.

Comment: Желаю вам не сдаваться и еще немного "побарахтаться". Лично я уже прошел этот этап после полугодового активного участия. Только подкосили меня не вопросы, а ответы, которые прямо противоположны цели, прописанной в манифесте: `Создать мир, в котором на каждый запрос к поисковику, в выдаче есть ссылка на развёрнутый ответ на русском языке`

Comment: Спасибо за внимание к вопросу. @РустамГимранов, и за пожелание)) конечно пытаюсь относиться философски, но честно говоря, не выходит - надежда только на техн. средства.

Comment: Это же запрос был задан на [главной мете в более расширенной форме (игнорирование ответов и комментариев)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3353/346987). Технически вам смогут помочь толоко юзер-скрипты.